# Simple probability binomial question

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider six life insurance policies on independent lives. Each of the four policies has a prob of 2/3 of giving rise to a claim within a year, each of the other two policies has a prob of 1/3 of giving rise to a cliam within the next year. Assume that only one claim can arise from each policy.

Calculate the probability that two policies chosen at random from the six will both give rise to claims within the next year.

Attempt:

denote $X_1 \sim Bin(4,2/3), X_2 \sim Bin(2,1/3)$ and let $Y \sim Bin (6,p)$

where $p = P((X_1 + X_2) = 2)$, we then want $P(Y=2) = 15p^2(1-p)^4$, so all there is left to do is find $p$. We have $$P((X_1 +X_2) = 2) = P(X_1 = 1 \cap X_2 = 1) + P(X_1=2 \cap X_1 = 0) + P(X_2 = 2 \cap X_1 = 0)$$
which I find to be $p = 43/243$, which leads to $P(Y=2) = 0.2155$, which is incorrect (correct answer is 0.3037 which is calculated using tree-diagrams)

Any help please

Comment: Just to say, this is a very unhealthy group of people.  Have you calculated the probability that you draw two unhealthy folk?  Two relatively healthy folk?  One of each?

Comment: Yes, thats built into $p$

Comment: It is hard to follow your calculation.  Not sure what $Y$ represents, for example.

Comment: To be clear:  your answer seems too low.  True, if you happen to draw two healthy folk then you only have a $\frac 19$ chance of both claims.  But that is very unlikely.  Even if you draw one of each type you have a $\frac 29$ chance and that is already higher than your answer.  I think you are miscalculating the probability distribution of the sample mix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you randomly pick the 1st policy out of the $6$ you have $4/6$ prob. that it is of type A and $2/6$ that it is of type $B$.
The prob. of the second will depend on the first. So
$(A,A):4/6 \, \cdot \,3/5=12/30$
$(A,B):4/6 \, \cdot \,2/5=8/30$
$(B,A):2/6 \, \cdot \,4/5=8/30$
$(B,B):2/6 \, \cdot \,1/5=2/30$
and the total is correctly $1$. Therefore
$P=12/30 \cdot (2/3)^2+16/30 \cdot(1/3)(2/3)+2/30 \cdot (1/3)^2=(48+32+2)/270=41/135$